# Blueimp jQuery File Upload with Additional title field editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

Using http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ I am trying to add a title field to go with uploaded image.  Once uploaded I want to be able to edit the title field for each image.  I am associating each image with an entity in the database successfully but I can't find a way to add and edit an additional title field.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any data to send with the `formData` option. [Let's see the documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#formdata).

You also can add data to the data object, it's the same object you'll get with the response:

```
.on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) 
{
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) 
    {
        file.myTitle = 'anyThing';
    });
});
```

With both solution you can add your title and an extra parameter to inform your DB if it's an edit or an insert.